# Can Python remove elements from a list that have any uncapitalized word?

Tags: python, list, loops, capitalize

thanks for looking.  I'm still working on my named entity recognition project, and I'm almost done.  My project was to extract all the names of people from a long string, and I've gotten to the point where I have a list of names, which I have named ent3.

This list has some artifacts from previous processing that are incorrect.  Specifically, I have elements in the list like 'Josie husband' or 'Laura fingernail'.  I want to eliminate those elements completely.

Is there a way to make Python iterate over the list and remove any elements that contain an UNcapitalized word?

Comment: It would be a very odd limitation on Python if it was impossible to use it to remove elements from a list that have uncapitalized words.

Comment: The answer to "is it possible" is usually "yes" -- you're using a general-purpose language on a general-purpose computer, so you have full Turing potential.  The implied question behind this, "how do I do it?" is an open-ended, individualized tutorial, which is *seriously* off-topic for Stack Overflow -- please re-take the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python find capitalized words", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: if you import `from string import ascii_uppercase`, then you can do something like: `[w for w in world_list if all(l in ascii_uppercase for l in w)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are

```
names = [
    'Jose Maria',
    'Alex Qqq',
    'Alex daddy',
    'Maria Fernandez',
    'Joe Dohn',
    'Dani mother'
]

clean = [x for x in names if not any((word.lower() == word for word in x.split()))]

print(clean)
```

Outputs

```
['Jose Maria', 'Alex Qqq', 'Maria Fernandez', 'Joe Dohn']
```

Comment: That worked.  Thank you!